# When is session serialized and deserialized, if using ASP.NET and RedisSessionStateProvider?

Tags: asp.net, session, redis

If you use [RedisSessionStateProvider](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers) to store your session state, when does it send/read information from Redis? From [this GitHub question](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/46), it sounds like deserializing the data is done on demand (i.e. at the moment I call `Session[key]`), but is that data loaded only once per request?

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the [diff](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/commit/14b9e51a53b22bfeae816600a06d750e389765fc#diff-b843c3b79a632e328c2513b337362452R19) that added deserialization/serialization on demand, the bytes for the entire session are deserialized on demand, but only loaded once ([here](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/commit/14b9e51a53b22bfeae816600a06d750e389765fc#diff-f4c5ab6b6c760e69471d13f8f3cdc4f8R215), in `GetSessionData`).
2. `GetSessionData` is [called](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/57) by the `HttpModule` `SessionStateModule` in [`BeginAcquireState`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/SessionStateModule.cs,74dccc58986964b8). So session loading should happen once during the AcquireRequestState event, which happens once per request.
3. It looks like session is saved during `ReleaseRequestState`, so once at the end of each request